# SIGABRT/Unrecognized Selector

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

My app is essentially a collection of cards, each with various messages/information on it. One swipes to go through these cards, generally swiping right. I am currently getting this sig abrt error:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

It also prints, this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[filterPageViewController askForPushNotifications]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8b6d0acd80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa92d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f506deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa9bd3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9e1cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9e18a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Lettuce                             0x000000010a2780a6 -[DraggableViewBackground cardSwipedRight:] + 2470
    6   Lettuce                             0x000000010a2d0ad5 -[DraggableView rightAction] + 453
    7   Lettuce                             0x000000010a2d02ed -[DraggableView afterSwipeAction] + 77
    8   Lettuce                             0x000000010a2cfe22 -[DraggableView beingDragged:] + 1922
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d9c7b28 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 153
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d9c419a _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 162
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d9c2197 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 843
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d9ca655 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898 + 79
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d9ca4f3 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 342
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d9b7e75 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2634
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d54448e -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d5456c4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d4f0dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d4ca553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9b8301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9ae22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9ad6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9ad0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001107e2ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010d4cff09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    25  Lettuce                             0x000000010a2c3f0f main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011012492d start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

After some investigating, I have found the problematic code. It is a line within my cardSwipedRight method that is in my draggableviewbackground class (this class functions as a deck, to hold all of the cards) :

```
                [((settingsTableViewController *)([obj.superNavController.viewControllers[obj.profileNum] viewControllers][0])) askForPushNotifications];
```

This line of code is within an if statement that checks whether this is a "sign me up for notifications card". What I'm confused by, is why xcode associated filterPageView with askForPushNotifications. Not only does filterPageView not have a askForPushNotifications method, but I don't swipe right on filterPageView nor have I viewed it by the time my app crashes.

Comment: Do your filterPageViewController have a method called askForPushNotifications?

Comment: Found the error so. You're calling it where you shouldn't.

Comment: I dont see where filterPageViewController calls askForPushNotifications though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One receives an unrecognized selector exception when the object to which the selector is sent does not implement/respond to the sent selector. In simple words, if a class A does not implement a method and someone try to call that method on an object of class A, runtime throws an unrecognized selector exception.

When we are not sure whether an object will respond to a selector, we should have a safety check to see if an object responds to intended selector.

For eg.

```
if ([*obj* respondsToSelector:@selector(*selector*)]) 
{
   [*obj* performSelector:*selector*];
}
```

Comment: so in my askForPushNotifications method, I should have this if statement as a safety check?

Comment: Or should I have this if statement before, " [((settingsTableViewController *)([obj.superNavController.viewControllers[obj.profileNum] viewControllers][0])) askForPushNotifications]; "

Comment: Yes, you should always have **respondsToSelector** check whenever you are not sure whether the object will respond to a method. This way you will avoid these kinds of crashes.

Answer (score 0):

unrecognized selector sent to instance comes up when you try to call a method on an object but that method doesn't exist (The corrrect terminology is that you have tried to send a message called "askForPushNotifications" but the settingsTableViewController does not understand it as it(askForPushNotifications) doesn't exit . I am sure you may not have that method in your settingsTableViewController. Please check and let me know if that helped you.

Also, please check with respondsToSelector if the object actually responds to the method askForPushNotifications. It may be the case that

> ((settingsTableViewController
>   *)([obj.superNavController.viewControllers[obj.profileNum] viewControllers][0]))

may not be of type SettingsTableViewController. Please check

```
if [(((settingsTableViewController *)([obj.superNavController.viewControllers[obj.profileNum] viewControllers][0])) respondsToSelector:@selector(askForPushNotifications)]
{
    [((settingsTableViewController *)([obj.superNavController.viewControllers[obj.profileNum] viewControllers][0])) askForPushNotifications];
}
```

Comment: askForPushNotifications is in my settingsTableViewController though :/

Comment: Is it declared in the .h file?

Comment: Yes, it is also declared in the .h file

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. I see Anup also responded with a similar answer. Please mark one as the correct answer which was helpful to you.